# How to test whether communication with API server over HTTPS is actually encrypted?

Tags: ssl, https

I am developing an app that communicates with an API server secured with HTTPS. How can I check whether the requests are actually encrypted in transit? Are there any tools that can intercept the requests?

Comment: If you're using HTTPS it is encrypted by default and by definition, unless you enable some bozo cipher suite.

Comment: Would it be safe to assume that if in the browser I can see the SSL cert is verified and the lock appears in the address bar that HTTPS is working as intended? By extension, would this mean that if I am able to retrieve the data at all that HTTPS is working, and otherwise the server would not respond with the API data?

Comment: 1. Of course, that's what the padlock means. 2. Of course. Unclear why you're asking.